# Simple Operator question. +=

Tags: c++, variables, operators

So my friend gave me some source code to start out with so I could review and understand it and I have a question about it, but since he's not online I thought I would try here, mainly I don't quite understand this line.

```
num += i;
```

Essentially, this is the same as

```
num = num + i
```

right?

If you need more details please tell me! I look forward to hearing your replies soon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From ISO C++03 (Section 5.17/7)

`The behavior of an expression of the form  E1 op= E2 is equivalent to  E1 = E1 op E2 except that E1 is evaluated only once.`

Comment: This is the best answer but hardest for me to understand, it took a second to understand what you meant by op but I got it.

Comment: The "evaluated only once" can make a significantdifference, for instance, if E1 is an indexed array position, where the index is not a constant. Example: arr[random()]=arr[random()]+1; vs. arr[random()]+=1;

Comment: nice find i did not know theres even an ISO for this. Thanks!

Comment: @Lars D: Assuming `random()` returns a [pseudo]random number, the expression `arr[random()] = arr[random()] + 1` may modify different `arr` elements, which I think is not the intention. The concept of "Common Subexpression Eliminator" may be relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is exactly the same (assuming you are talking about the built-in `+=`). In fact, this is how `+=` is defined in the language specification.

Doesn't your favorite C++ book cover this topic?

Comment: Ah it says the same thing, I guess I skimmed the page too fast and missed it. :P Thanks man!

Comment: It is most certainly not the same thing, especially if num is not a primitive type. Classes can overload `operator+` and `operator+=` to perform completely different operations (which is ill-advised, but quite legal).

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: That's why I added the "assuming you are talking about the *built-in* `+=`" bit. The term "built-in operator" in C++ terminology specifically refers to non-overloaded operator. For the built-in operator, once again, it *is* the same thing for the original examples.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially yes, but it is more efficient.  For basic types, like integers, using `num += i` increments the value of `num` directly, whereas `num = num + i` creates a temporary of the value of `num`, increments it, and then assigns it back to `num`.

Comment: It will make absolutely no difference with any modern compiler.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the extra info, I'm really new to programming, I"m just going it with google, and some sites, and advice. So any info like that is nice to know. Now I know what it does, the difference, and that it doesn't matter nowadays. Thanks guys.

Comment: Yeah, any modern compiler should recognize them to be the same. The GCC compiler can do some amazing things when it comes to optimization.

Answer (score 0):

What will really happen there, as posted before, depends on the language.  If one assumes C++, and that num is an integer, then as others have posted and as you have

```
num += i;
```

is equivalent to

```
num = num + i;
```

But it is really up to the class to determine that behavior in c++ / c#.  You will essentially call the "+=" operator on the num object for the i object type.  This should, in a good design, be the same as first performing the "+" operator, and then performing the = operator in the manner above.  But it doesn't have to be:

```
 class foo
 {
     bool operator += (int i) {return false;}
 }

 foo num;
 int i;

 bool result = num += i;
```

In that example, num will be unchanged, and result will be false.

Comment: And it is really ill-advised to ever change the signature / meaning of an operator when overloading it, unless you are creating a DSEL of course.

Comment: @Matthieu M - no doubt on that.  I hope it didn't come across like I was saying that was in any way what should ever happen.  If a class ever uses += to not be a combination of the + and = operators, the author has some 'splainin' ta do.